# Make two simple regex's into one

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a regex that will look behind .txt and then behind the "-" and get the first digit .... in the example, it would be a 1.

```
$record_pattern = '/.txt.+/';
preg_match($record_pattern, $decklist, $record);
print_r($record);

.txt?n=chihoi%20%283-1%29
```

I want to write this as one expression but can only seem to do it as two.  This is the first time working with regex's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
\.txt[^-]*-\K\d
```

You don't need for any groups. It just matches from the `.txt` and upto the literal `-`. Because of `\K` in our regex, it discards the previously matched characters. In our case it discards `.txt?n=chihoi%20%283-` string. Then it starts matching again the first digit which was just after to `-`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vF5yH2/2)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = ".txt?n=chihoi%20%283-1%29";
$regex = '~\.txt[^-]*-\K\d~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> 1
```

Comment: ty for the link ... I just found a page like this that wasnt as good, so thanks for the upgrade!

Comment: @six7zero9 first go for matching. If matching a specific character is not possible then go for grouping.

Comment: thanks for the help ... regex still seems a bit like magic, trying to figure it out with the tester page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$record_pattern = '/\.txt.+-(\d)/';
```

Now, the first group contains what you want.

Comment: This worked also ... I dont really know which way is "better", but the answer below worked too... thanks for the help!